# Would iteration over Cassandra rows with LIMIT and OFFSET have any unexpected side effects?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

My Project has a huge Cassadra Table. My Cassadra running with 5 nodes in a kubernetes. As Backend I use Spring Boot 2.X.

I try to update values in my entire Table. Because of the size of the table I do not use a "SELECT * FROM TABLE" query.

Instead I think about to use "**limit**" with "**offset**"

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset;
```

With recursive call

```
private boolean migrateBookingTable(Database database, Statement statement, String tableName, int limit, int offset) throws SQLException, LiquibaseException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset;
    try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql)) {
        //if resultSet is empty, we are done
        if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()) {
            return false;
        }
        while (resultSet.next()) {
         //some logic
        }
        database.execute...
    }

    return migrateBookingTable(database, statement, tableName, limit, offset+limit);
}
```

I tested it on a small test environment. Its worked. But because of cassandra peculiarities and the fact of 5 Nodes on production. Im not sure about side effects.

Is this an "ok" way to go?

Answer (score 1):

`OFFSET` is not part of CQL language, not sure how you tested.

```
cqlsh:ks1> select * from user LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
SyntaxException: line 1:27 mismatched input 'OFFSET' expecting EOF (...* from user LIMIT 1 [OFFSET]...)
```

> Because of the size of the table I do not use a "SELECT * FROM TABLE" query.

Without the awful `findAll()` allowed by Spring Data Cassandra every request is paged with Cassandra. Why not going with the default [behaviour of Paging with the cassandra drivers.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/manual/core/paging/)

```
SimpleStatement statement = QueryBuilder.selectFrom(USER_TABLENAME).all().build()
 .setPageSize(10)                    // 10 per pages
 .setTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))  // 1s timeout
 .setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
 ResultSet page1 = session.execute(statement);
        
 LOGGER.info("+ Page 1 has {} items", 
 page1.getAvailableWithoutFetching());
 Iterator<Row> page1Iter = page1.iterator();
 while (0 <  page1.getAvailableWithoutFetching()) {
   LOGGER.info("Page1: " + page1Iter.next().getString(USER_EMAIL));
 }

 // Getting ready for page2
 ByteBuffer pagingStateAsBytes = page1.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();
 statement.setPagingState(pagingStateAsBytes);
 ResultSet page2 = session.execute(statement);
```

Spring Data Also allow paging with [Slice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters)